# Write $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{S(n)-S(n-1)}{n^3}$ as an integral, where $S(m)$ denotes the sum of remainders function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

If I'm right it is easy to write in closed-form the series $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{S(n)-S(n-1)}{n^3},\tag{1}$$
where for integers $m\geq 1$, the arithmetic function $S(m)$ is defined as $$S(m)=\sum_{k=1}^m m\text{ mod }k,\tag{2}$$ that is, the $S(m)$ is the so-called sum of remainders function.

**Example.** For $m=5$, one has that $$S(5)=5\text{ mod }1+5\text{ mod }2+5\text{ mod }3+5\text{ mod }4+5\text{ mod }5=0+1+2+1+0=4.\square$$

Then yesterday while I wrote those symbolic calculations I wondered if is it possible to write a sum likes previous $(1)$ as an integral, having such integral representation a simple form.

> **Question.** Write as a simple (definite) integral, any, the quantity 
>   $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{S(n)-S(n-1)}{n^3}.$$
>   **Many thanks.**

Isn't required that you calculate the value of this real number since I know it, j, that I am asking is about a simple integral representation for this real number $(1)$. What is your solution? You can use the properties of the integral that you need (Lebesgue, Riemann, Stieltjes).

Comment: Well $S(k)=\sum_{n=1}^k (((k-1) \mod n)  +1)[n \nmid k]=\sum_{n=1}^k(((k-1) \mod n)+1) -\sum_{n=1}^k(((k-1)\mod n)+1)[n \mid k] = S(k-1) +2k-1 - \sigma_1(k)$ so your sum reduces to $\frac{\pi^2}{3}-\zeta(3)(1+\frac{\pi^2}{6})$ without even using an integral.

Comment: Yes, I believe that it is the same real number that I've calculated using a theorem involving the sum of remainders function, and particular values of Dirichlet series. Thus many thanks for your attention and help. On the other hand I am asking in this MSE about integral representations as a definite integrals of $(1)$ @Jacob

Comment: Many thanks @DaríoA.Gutiérrez for your edit and attention.